# Yii2: how to change/add response headers?

Tags: php, http, web, yii2

I have some truble with Yii2. I try to add/set response headers in my controller's action. Below is code:

```
   Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-type', ['application/pdf']);
   Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', ['inline', 'filename=' . $fileName]);
   Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', ['binary']);
   Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Length', [$fileSize]);
   Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Accept-Ranges', ['bytes']);

   return readfile($filePath);
```

If I change set() to add(), or second argument from array to string so get no reaction. Pdf file is not opened. But if I use native PHP header() method - all works correct.

Comment: Look setDownloadHeaders function in Response class

Comment: @ConorHolt, nope, doesn't work
Yii::$app->response->setDownloadHeaders($fileName, 'application/pdf', true, $fileSize);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `set` signature expects string as value so it would be better to replace your arrays with string although it not makes any difference in non-strict coding.

Anyway - based on the [getDispositionHeaderValue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.10/framework/web/Response.php#L743) `Content-Disposition` should be

```
'inline; filename=' . $fileName
```

It would be better to use Yii 2 methods to send the file to browser like:

- [sendContentAsFile](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.10/framework/web/Response.php#L486)
- [sendFile](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.10/framework/web/Response.php#L454)

Comment: Sure, I can use native header() function, but I think  I should work in Yii2 way

Comment: I need just open pdf document in browser :)

Comment: So `sendFile` is exactly what you need.

Comment: That method offer me to save file, so I need to open pdf in browser window(by default PDFViewer.js).

Comment: See [inline](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.10/framework/web/Response.php#L446) param

Comment: Omg, it's a big fail, big fail. Thank you very much for helping. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Yii2 super easy way to send files as download is

```
public function actionDownload()
{
    return \Yii::$app->response->sendFile('path/to/file.txt');
}
```

For more info see [the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#sending-files)